# click trigger on bootstrap datepicker jQuery addClass not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap DatePciker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org) , and I want to add a Click event on days (td), When I click on any day, add class to that day (td). but it does not work.

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    todayBtn: true
});

$('tbody').on('click','td.day',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/2L1ovhbm/8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `changeDate` event of datePicker.

Docs: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html

```
$('#calendar').datepicker('setDates', events)
    .on('changeDate', function (e) {
        // $(this).addClass('clicked'); // $(this) here is not what you think.
        $('.active').addClass('clicked');
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2L1ovhbm/13/